# Can I use Jenkins to create an EAR file for manual deployment?

Tags: jenkins

is it possible use Jenkins to create an EAR file for manual deployment? This is because I use Geronimo and cannot find any suitable plugins for automated deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you won't really be using Jenkins to produce the EAR file specifically; Jenkins will run your existing build using Maven, Ant, Gradle or whatever mechanism you use, triggering the build on a schedule or after a change to your SCM system, and archive the EAR file in a given directory.

You might be able to take this further by using the [Deploy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin), which can deploy a JAR or EAR file to a running application server.

Comment: right. I understand now, so it archives the EAR. I would like to use the deploy plugin but it does not support geronimo.